# how to find largest positive or negative value pattern from a given standpoint

Tags: vba, design-patterns

I'm currently writing a sub but I'm unclear of how to approach the problem programatically

Essentially I have a sheet with a column of data values starting at "A1"

How do I write a sub that will check through the column to find the largest pattern starting from the first cell and the direction of the pattern?

ie. if A1 is 2, A2 is 5, A3 is -2 ... the sub should return 2 (positive 2 days in a row)
    if A1 is -2, A2 -1, A3 is -5, A4 is -2, A5 -1, A6 2 ... the sub should return -5 (negative 5 days in a row)

What I want is to somehow gather this number but in the process also save the last row in the pattern so I can compute averages, std variation etc. to store to a collection

Here is the code to check for patterns.... the j is a column counter... I need to figure out how to make the loop go back up to right before the for loop instead of iterating the j variable and then going back down....

but in any case here is the check pattern sub

```
<i> Sub pattern_recogADR()

'add back in as parameters
x As Long
pat_days As Long
sht_start As Long


x = 1
pat_days = 5
sht_start = 13


Dim st As Long
Dim st_num As Long
Dim st_end As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim patrn As Long

count = sht_start

Dim i As Long

Set pat = New pattern

For j = 8 To 12
    st_num = 0
        If IsNumeric(Cells(count, j).value) Then
            st_num = count 'sets default pattern to beginning cell value

                If Cells(st_num, j).value < 0 Then
                    For i = count + 1 To count + 1 + pat_days
                        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).value) And Cells(i, j).value < 0 Then
                            st_end = i
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i

                        patrn = st_end - st_num

                        tix.arbPnl = patrn
                        '**CONFUSION HERE WANT TO SAVE PATTERN TO AN EXISTING COLLECTION STARTING `    
                        'AT THE FIRST ITEM **


                ElseIf Cells(st_num, j).value > 0 Then
                    For i = count + 1 To count + 1 + pat_days
                        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).value) And Cells(i, j).value < 0 Then
                            st_end = i
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i

                        patrn = st_end - st_num

                        TIX.arbPnl = patrn
                        'save to separate class for patterns


        Else
            count = count + 1
        End If
Next j




End Sub
```

Here is where I previously define the object. Basically I want to get this pattern and then add it to the respective attribute (? I dont know coding vocab) in this collection which is already define so the pattern matches with the respective item in the collection.

```
Option Explicit

Public TixCollection As New Collection

Sub DefineTixCollection()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Input").Activate
Set TixCollection = Nothing


Dim tix As clsTix
Dim i As Long
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Add tix properties
    For i = 3 To last_row
        Set tix = New clsTix

        'only adds active tickers to collection
        If Range("A" & i).value = "x" Then
            'Random data

            tix.ORD = Range("B" & i).value
            tix.ADR = Range("C" & i).value
            tix.ratio = Range("D" & i).value
            tix.crrncy = Range("E" & i).value
            tix.hedge_index = Range("F" & i).value
            tix.hedge_ord = Range("G" & i).value
            tix.hedge_ratio = Range("H" & i).value

            ' ADR is the id key
            TixCollection.Add tix, tix.ADR
        End If

    Next i

' Error Check
  '  For i = 1 To 5
  '      'retrieve by collection index
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(i).ORD
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(5).ADR
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(5).ratio
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(i).crrncy
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(i).hedge_index
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(i).hedge_ord
  '      Debug.Print TixCollection(i).hedge_ratio
  '  Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated getting frustrated now... ugh

Comment: just keep a count of positive or negative numbers in a loop until it changes.

Comment: i'm really confused on how to do this... see my biggest problem is not all the data points are values so i want to start counting from where the number is numeric. Also I want to loop across columns as well.. also your suggestion doesnt help bc if the number is positive or negative says nothing about the previous number.

Comment: You could use isnumber worksheet function to tell if the cell contains a number, if it does you can check if the value is negative or positive and set a boolean to keep track of this. If the next cell contains a number check if it has the same sign (positive or negative) as the boolean if it is add one to the count etc. It would probably help if you showed the code you have developed so far.

Comment: ok the code is getting a bit more complicated because I'm trying to add the value I get to a collection that already exists as a public variable... i'll post code now

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim patrn() As Long
    ReDim patrn(0 To 4)

    Dim count As Long
    Dim posCount As Integer
    Dim negCount As Integer
    Dim sign As Boolean

    posCount = 0
    negCount = 0
    count = 0

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long

    For j = 8 To 12
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, j).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                If count = 0 Then
                    If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                        sign = True
                        posCount = posCount + 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value < 0 Then
                        sign = False
                        negCount = negCount + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf count > 0 And count <= 4 Then
                    If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 And sign = True Then
                        sign = True
                        posCount = posCount + 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value > 0 And sign = False Then
                        sign = True
                        posCount = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value < 0 And sign = True Then
                        sign = False
                        negCount = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value < 0 And sign = False Then
                        sign = False
                        negCount = negCount + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf count = 5 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next i
        If posCount > negCount Then
            patrn(j - 8) = posCount
        Else
            patrn(j - 8) = negCount - (negCount * 2)
        End If
        negCount = 0
        posCount = 0
        count = 0
    Next j

    'Do your other calculations here.
    For i = LBound(patrn) To UBound(patrn)
        Debug.Print patrn(i)
    Next
End Sub
```